# Change Worksheet Name

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I am using the Excel Interop to create an excel file and output data to it and I want to change the worksheet name based on the user's selection from a comboBox.  However, I can not get input from a comboBox to display as the worksheet name.  I can however get the same value to display as the worksheet name if it is coming form a textbox.  I am even using `comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString()` and making it a string and then trying to apply that as the worksheet name.  Replacing any non-alpha characters with spaces did not work either.  The sting has only alpha characters and spaces but it won't replace the original worksheet name.

Here is the code I am using to try and change the worksheet name.

```
worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets.Add(Missing.Value, workbook.Worksheets[sheetCount], Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
workbook.Worksheets[sheetCountPlusONe].Name = "Results " + registrationForm.selectedEvent;
```

Comment: Have you tried using `comboBox.Text` instead of `comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString()`?

Comment: yes and it doesn't work.  this is a very frustrating little quirk with the excel interop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I am assuming that `registrationForm` is the combobox.

You have to use the `GetItemText` method which analyzes the selected item and finally returns the text of that item.

```
string WsName = this.registrationForm.GetItemText(this.registrationForm.SelectedItem);
```

**TRIED AND TESTED**

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.comboBox1.Items.Add("Sheet1111");
        this.comboBox1.Items.Add("Sheet2222");
        this.comboBox1.Items.Add("Sheet3333");
    }

   private void btnOPen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlexcel;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;

        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        xlexcel = new Excel.Application();

        xlexcel.Visible = true;

        //~~> Open a File
        xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\\sample.xlsx", 0, true, 5, "", "", true,
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);

        // Set Sheet 1 as the sheet you want to work with
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        string WsName = this.comboBox1.GetItemText(this.comboBox1.SelectedItem);

        xlWorkSheet.Name = WsName;

       //
       //~~> Rest of code
       //
    }
```